# Question about the logic of a simple C++ function (is_palindrome)

Tags: c++, palindrome

The function below is supposed to check if the input parameter is a palindrome and return true/false.

I know that there is a mistake in the code, it's supposed to be: int i = text.size() **- 1**;

**Question:** if I don't add "-1" and print out text and textR, both of them would be "madam" and in my understanding when I check (text == textR) it's supposed to be true. It does return `false`, however.

Could someone please explain what am I missing?

I understand that it has something to do with `string.size()` and string contents not being the same thing and that a string index starts with a 0... I still don't fully get why text != textR.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

// Define is_palindrome() here:

bool is_palindrome(std::string text) {

  // create an empty string to store a reversed version of text 
  std::string textR;

// iterating backward over text and adding each character to textR
  for (int i = text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
    textR.push_back(text[i]);
  }

std::cout << text << std::endl;
std::cout << textR << std::endl;

  // check if the reversed text is the same as text; return true or false

  if (text == textR) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

int main() {

  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";

}
```

Comment: `return text == textR;` is equivalent to `if (text == textR) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }`.

Comment: Side note: from a performance perspective this algorithm is pretty questionable.

Comment: Using `std::reverse_iterator` would also avoid the issue: `const std::string textR(text.rbegin(), text.rend());`

Comment: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/2Tx5XS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`text[text.size()]` is `'\0'` (nul character) which is not printable.

so `TextR` is `"\0madam"` instead of expected `"madam"`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is given and accepted. Good.

Additionally, I would like to give the answer for a more or less standard solution for this function.

This is a typical one liner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s) { return s == std::string(s.crbegin(), s.crend()); };

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Is HannaH a palindrome?: " << is_palindrome("HannaH") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```